# How should i prevent tab key to activate my radio button, but it still should be able to focus on text of radio button

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

When I'm tabbing through a wizard dialog in swt which contains text boxes, radio buttons, push buttons. Problem is whenever I tab through a disabled radio button which looks like ()radioText, this is getting activated like this (.):radioText:, along with this radio buttons, there are 2 text boxes which are to acting the same way when tab key is clicked. So what is the way so that tab should focus on the radio button but it should not activate it, I mean from ()radioText state to (.)radioText state. Could some one share their experience in implementing this.

Comment: I don't think you wanted to say that the radio is disabled. Probably not selected. If it is disabled, it cannot get focus.

Comment: FWIW, I don't see this behavior, at least with SWT from Eclipse 4.4. A set of radio buttons *with the same parent Composite* appear to group themselves automatically, so that at most one is selected, and only the selected one is in the tab order. None of the workarounds below have been necessary for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an ugly solution, but it works.

Instead of allowing focus to get directly to the radio button, you can put another hidden control before it. In my cases, I used a canvas. When that control gets focus, get the selection for the radio buttons following it, set the focus to the first radio button, and then revert the selection back to what it used to be. This works for forward traversal. For backward (CTRL+TAB), you have to do the same with a hidden control after the radio buttons.

Be aware that with this solution selection listeners can be fired during tab traversal. But after it the selection will be as before.

Here is a small snippet that does this. It only works in forward mode, and the canvas is not really hidden. You have to fix the layout for you case.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    new Button(shell, SWT.TOGGLE);
    new Scale(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);

    final Canvas invisible = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
    invisible.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        }
    });

    final Button radioButton1 = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
    radioButton1.setText("text1");

    final Button radioButton2 = new Button(shell, SWT.RADIO);
    radioButton2.setText("text2");

    invisible.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            final boolean selection1 = radioButton1.getSelection();
            final boolean selection2 = radioButton2.getSelection();
            radioButton1.setFocus();
            radioButton1.setSelection(selection1);
            radioButton2.setSelection(selection2);
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        }
    });

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: at the same time, it has text boxes beside radio button, text box also getting its selection to true whenever it is setting focus on text box. Is there any way ?, i see that check boxes work normally, that they don't get selected whenever focus is set on them, what makes radio button differs in them when focus is set on them?

Comment: @suj the radio group is designed for cases where exactly one option is chosen (like buttons on old [radios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button), where one pops up only when you pressed another one). Theoretically you should never have radio button groups with no button selected. You are not using radio buttons for what they were designed. That's why you need hacks like the one above. I did not understand your first question from the comment.

Comment: What i meant in the first question is beside the radio button in the wizard dialog, there are two text boxes where tabbing on them also making tem active from inactive state, like from grayed state to non-grayed state

Comment: @suj Indeed, if you have text boxes next to radio buttons my solution does not work. `setTabList` does not work, either. On selection event you have no source info to find out if it comes from focus or from mouse click or space pressed. I would probably put key and mouse listeners, save last event and revert or not selection based on that. I didn't have the time to test this. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: yeah what you've said is right, i've tried a lot, but didn't work. I didn't try the key and mouse listeners

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for the case where there is a text field after the radio button. In other cases my other answer can be used. It is not perfect, and it is quite ugly, but maybe it solves your problem.

Besides the internal state, I keep the selection value as data (`setData()`) and update the *official* selection after each selection event.

Here is the complete snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NO_RADIO_GROUP);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    new Button(composite, SWT.TOGGLE);
    new Scale(composite, SWT.HORIZONTAL);

    final Button radioButton1 = new Button(composite, SWT.RADIO);
    radioButton1.setText("text1");
    radioButton1.setData("selection", false);
    new Text(composite, SWT.SINGLE);

    final Button radioButton2 = new Button(composite, SWT.RADIO);
    radioButton2.setText("text2");
    radioButton2.setData("selection", false);
    new Text(composite, SWT.SINGLE);

    final Button[] radioGroup = {radioButton1, radioButton2};

    final Listener listener = new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            final Button button = (Button) event.widget;
            switch (event.type) {
                case SWT.MouseDown:
                    event.widget.setData("selection", true);
                    break;
                case SWT.KeyDown:
                    if (event.keyCode == SWT.SPACE) {
                        event.widget.setData("selection", true);
                    }
                    break;
                case SWT.Selection:
                    final boolean selection = (boolean) button.getData("selection");
                    if (selection != button.getSelection()) {
                        button.setSelection(selection);
                    }
                    if (selection) {
                        for (Button radioButton : radioGroup) {
                            if (radioButton != button) {
                                radioButton.setData("selection", false);
                                radioButton.setSelection(false);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    radioButton1.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, listener);
    radioButton1.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, listener);
    radioButton1.addListener(SWT.Selection, listener);
    radioButton2.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, listener);
    radioButton2.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, listener);
    radioButton2.addListener(SWT.Selection, listener);

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: it serves the purpose for now, i will try any ways thanks for sharing your info

Comment: i solved the answer in other way, like putting radio buttons in the same composites, it goes only to the active radio button states. I just wanna share the answer with you, thanks for your suggestions and code

Comment: @suj oh, assumed you _wanted_ to have radio group with no button selected. If you have one selected, then putting all buttons in the same composite is clearly the way to do it.

Comment: i liked your answer, it may be helpful in some cases. Good Try

Answer (score 0):

```
package myexamples;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.layout.grouplayout.GroupLayout;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.layout.grouplayout.LayoutStyle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;

public class MySample {
    private static Text text;
    private static Text text_1;
    private static Text text_2;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell = new Shell();

        Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setBounds(197, 177, 393, 110);
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);

        Button btnButton = new Button(composite, SWT.RADIO);
        btnButton.setText(" Button1");

        Composite composite_1 = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
        composite_1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));
        GridData gd_composite_1 = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
        gd_composite_1.heightHint = 37;
        gd_composite_1.widthHint = 306;
        composite_1.setLayoutData(gd_composite_1);

        text = new Text(composite_1, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setSize(new Point(10, 8));
        GridData gd_text = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1);
        gd_text.widthHint = 72;
        text.setLayoutData(gd_text);

        Label lblLabel = new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        lblLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
        lblLabel.setText("Label2");

        text_1 = new Text(composite_1, SWT.BORDER);
        text_1.setSize(new Point(12, 8));
        GridData gd_text_1 = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1);
        gd_text_1.widthHint = 60;
        text_1.setLayoutData(gd_text_1);

        Label lblLabel_1 = new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        lblLabel_1.setText(" Label3");
        new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);

        Button btnButton_1 = new Button(composite, SWT.RADIO);
        btnButton_1.setText(" Button2");

        Composite composite_2 = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
        composite_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, false));
        GridData gd_composite_2 = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
        gd_composite_2.widthHint = 305;
        gd_composite_2.heightHint = 30;
        composite_2.setLayoutData(gd_composite_2);

        Combo combo = new Combo(composite_2, SWT.NONE);
        combo.setSize(new Point(10, 8));
        combo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
        combo.setEnabled(false);
        Combo combo_1 = new Combo(composite_2, SWT.NONE);
        combo_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
        combo_1.setEnabled(false);
        Label lblLabelxyz = new Label(composite_2, SWT.NONE);
        lblLabelxyz.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
        lblLabelxyz.setText("LabelXYZ1");

        text_2 = new Text(composite_2, SWT.BORDER);
        text_2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

        Label lblLabelxyz_1 = new Label(composite_2, SWT.NONE);
        lblLabelxyz_1.setText("LabelXYZ2");
        text_2.setEnabled(false);
        Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        label.setBounds(62, 112, 55, 15);
        label.setText("");
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a form, if you want to ask a question to a user and that question requires a Yes/No answer, it is nice to display empty options.

Besides it is clearer if the user is not able to provide an answer, as he can clearly see what was left out in the form.

This indeed requires a tweak (as the answers above suggest). I achieved it by adding a 3rd button that I artificially hide and that gets the initial selection (i.e. the "true" value).

```
Composite c = toolkit.createComposite(parent);
c.setLayout(new RowLayout());

yesButton = toolkit.createButton(c, "Yes", SWT.RADIO);
noButton = toolkit.createButton(c, "No", SWT.RADIO);

yesButton.setSelection(false);
noButton.setSelection(false);

hiddenButton = toolkit.createButton(c, "", SWT.RADIO);
hiddenButton.setSelection(true);
hiddenButton.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
    @Override
    public void paintControl(PaintEvent paintevent) {
        // before you paint, shrink the button size to zero
        ((Button)paintevent.widget).setSize(0, 0);
    }
});
```

The trick is that you cannot hide the button using setVisible(false), otherwise, the next button in the row will get the selection.

To work around that, you can force the size of the component to zero by intercepting the PaintEvents on the button